# I do not want to show error message VBA Userform

Tags: vba, userform

I am building a userform where someone has to put in numbers, however if they accidentaly put in a letter and hit continue they get a type mismatch. I want to make it so that instead of the error, they get a Messagebox that says that they have entered an invalid character and to restart the form.

my code is entered below. I hope you can understand my question and code and are able to help me

```
On Error GoTo Start
MsgBox "Your Have Entered Invalid Characters, Please Try Again", vbOKOnly, "Error"

Start:
'Assigning Varaible
Dim Dec, GST, PST As Single
Dim TC, FPrice, NTC, Tax, FTC As Double
Dim Province As String

'Confirming Decimal
If NineSeven = True Then
    Dec = 0.97
Else
    Dec = 0.99
End If

'Finalizing Price
FPrice = Price + Dec

'Calculating Transaction Cost
TC = Quantity * FPrice

'Adding discount
If TC > 2500 Then
    NTC = TC * 0.93
Else
    NTC = TC
End If

'Confirming Province
If Alberta = True Then
    GST = 0.05
    PST = 0
    Province = "Alberta"
ElseIf BritishColombia = True Then
    GST = 0.05
    PST = 0.07
    Province = "British Colombia"
ElseIf Saskachewan = True Then
    GST = 0.05
    PST = 0.06
    Province = "Saskachewan"
End If

'Caclulating Taxes
Tax = (NTC * GST) + (NTC * PST)

'Calculating Final Transaction Cost
FTC = NTC + Tax

Unload UserForm1
End sub
```

Comment: `Dim Dec, GST, PST As Single` Only PST is Single, other variables are Variant.
`Dim TC, FPrice, NTC, Tax, FTC As Double` Only FTC is Double, other variables are Variant. See [Dim statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dim-statement).

Answer (score 1):

Most of your code is irrelevant in that it's doing calculations after you've got a numerica value. I can't tell when you're collecting your inputs, but in this sample code, you can see how to handle an incorrect entry.

```
Sub ExampeEntry()
Dim aResponse As String, aNumberResponse As Double
   
start:
aResponse = InputBox("Enter A Number")
    
    If aResponse = "" Then
        'User cancelled/didn't enter
    ElseIf IsNumeric(aResponse) Then
        'move your string into a double variable
        aNumberResponse = aResponse
        'confirming the value
        MsgBox aNumberResponse
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid Entry", vbCritical, "C'mon man..."
        GoTo start
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Speaking from experience, you might want to take into account users who enter predictably wrong information such as `$` or `,` (or `.` if Europe). To account for such situations, I typically add some correction lines after the inputbox to strip out these characters...

```
aResponse = Replace(aResponse, ",", "")
aResponse = Replace(aResponse, "$", "")
```

(these could be in one line as part of inputbox but I'm just listing individually for illustration purposes)